# I have checked for null value but still get error saying I didn't checked

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

[image] I already have a null check before using the value but it still give me error[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make null-safety assertions to avoid using null check (!) or conditional (?) operators in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965949/how-can-i-make-null-safety-assertions-to-avoid-using-null-check-or-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put an `!` behind it to indicate you are sure it can't be null, so like

```
for (final value in widget.details.data.productPriceObjs!) {
```

If you don't like using `!` you can alternatively write

```
var objects = widget.details.data.productPriceObjs;
if (objects != null) {
  for (final value in objects) {
  
  }
}
```

Somehow the compiler is fine with it when there isn't "nesting" in the check

Answer (score 0):

Put `!` mark behind `widget.details.data.productPriceObjs` to make sure to compiler that this value is not null

For more details about null safety [read here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)